# Best way to ask the topics that the Interviewer will cover?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-description

I have a technical interview coming up and the job description covers a lot of topics. But, it will always be better for me to know what will they cover, so that I can prepare and project myself much better than giving general answers. What is the best way of asking the recruiter of what will the the interviewer cover without getting into a situation that entails considerable risks or having a negative impact?

P.S: I know some companies tell before hand the topics as a standard procedure for interviewing and evaluating the candidates.

Comment: "so that I can prepare" - they're probably interested in finding out what you know *without* having to 'prepare'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would phrase the question with something like:

> Hi XXXX,
>
> I'm really looking forward to our interview. I know that your time is valuable/limited and I am eager to assist you in the process. Therefore I was
>   wondering if there are any specific areas that you are particularly
>   interested in discussing in detail and I'll try to make sure that I
>   have all the relevant details available for you. if so please let me know otherwise I'll see you on such an such day/time.
>
> regards, ....etc....

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion I think it is not suitable to ask something like this. If you eager to know what they are going to ask do a small research rather than ask them directly.  There are number of ways to get information like this. You can get brief introduction about the company and business over the internet. Probably they will focus on their technologies, business strategies. If you know someone works there through them you can get more details about the interview. So there are many other ways to find information. Using these kind of information you can finalize what are they going to focus on.